# Can't get latitude of networkx node

Tags: python, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude, networkx

I have a networkx graph that has been imported from OpenStreetMap. The nodes have a node-ID, latitude and longitude. I'm trying to access the latter two, but so far with no success. My best attempt seems to be:

```
node.names = graph.nodes()  # get the node IDs
latitudes = nx.get_node_attributes(graph, 'lat')
first_node = node_names[0]
latitude latitudes[first_node]['lat']
```

The nx.get_node_attributes(graph, 'lat') indeed returns a dictionary consisting of node-IDs and the latitude, but when trying to access the latitude I get a "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable". 
Does anyone know how I can access it?

Comment: Please post a snippet of the `latitudes` dict.

Comment: When posting questions about errors you're getting, you should provide a [mcve].  I can't copy and paste your code and run it.  It also helps if you give  the full traceback of the error.  There are several places where the error message you see could be occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you present isn't what is actually giving the error because the last line has a syntax error in it (I think a missing `=` sign).

`"TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"` means that you are doing `a[x]` because you think `a` is a list or tuple or dict, but in actual fact `a` is a float, that can't be subscripted with `x`.

At a guess (I have to guess since you haven't given us the error message), if the line giving you the problem is this one:

`latitudes[first_node]['lat']`

then `latitudes[first_node']` is a float, most likely the latitude you are looking for.